# Need WPF MediaElement wrapper

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I've found a couple of good MediaElement wrappers for Silverlight, such as this one: http://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/
But I'm having trouble finding the equivalent for WPF.  Does this exist?

I'm looking for a wpf based video player that contains play, pause, video thumbnail, volume control, fast forward (with a buffer visible), etc.

Currently I'm just trying to port the Silverlight player linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Telerik's Website](http://www.telerik.com) - they have something really good, but it is not free.

Comment: I looked at Telerik's site, I didn't see anything in their SPF controls to play video.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/GuOrg/Gu.Wpf.Media

This is simple wrapper for WPF `mediaelement`object.

The player looks like this:

[image]

In the link above you will find a sample source code to start with. IMO pretty useful thing.